# Can「箱の中を手で探った」be shortened to 「箱を探った」?

Tags: written-language

By using default meanings, couldn't the title be shortened to:

> 箱を探った。

1. Isn't `の中` so obvious, it is assumed to be the location you searched? If I were to search **under** the box, then I *would* write `の下`?
2. Isn't `手で` so obvious, it is assumed to be with what you searched? If I were to search with my **foot**, then I *would* write `足で`?
3. In *formal written* Japanese, shouldn't you try to shorten your sentences as much as possible?
4. Is the following correct usage of `暗黙了解':

> この例では、`の中`も`手で`も暗黙了解です。

I am only talking about *formal writing*. Unnecessary words are naturally used in every language in conversation.

Comment: How would you say: “I looked for the box?”

Comment: @変幻出没 「箱を探**し**た」

Comment: @Ash Good point. I had a misleading translation for さぐる in my notebook (French has a verb than can cover both さぐる and さがす at once). Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 箱を探った usually means to search a box in a blind spot by touching the surface of it.
2. Even without 手で, it's usually interpreted so.
3. Not particularly.
4. 暗黙の了解 is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would say either "箱の中を探った”　or "箱を中を手で探った”.

箱を探った。is grammatically not wrong, but it just sounds not natural to me.